Astrotomic/laravel-translatable add new language dynamically
can somebody tell me please how to achieve this in astrotomic/laravel-translatable package?
I need to add new language to the app dynamically.
There is config/translatable.php which contains
'locales' => ['en', 'cs', 'cz', 'sk', 'pl',  'de', 'hu',  'uk',  'us', 'gb', ],

This does not allow to add new language which is not defined in this array. I have a controller which want to add new languages and tries to do it this way.
This lines runs before new lang is added to the app.
config([
    'translatable.locales'         => $newLocales,
    'translatable.locale'          => $data['default_language'],
    'translatable.fallback_locale' => $data['default_language'],
]);

I thought this will change the config and library will add new language. But the library allow only the languages which are in config file array.
How can I dynamically add new languages to the application?
Thanks.

what version is the Astrotomic/laravel-translatable?

Updating the config file is not great to do..  make sure to \Artisan::call('config:clear'); during update.

better to use DB to for locales crud

I solved the issue by load() method https://docs.astrotomic.info/laravel-translatable/package/locales-helper#load Is there a way to force the package to use database instead of config file?
